# UNC path is recognised as valid on an application deployed on most machines apart from two.

Tags: c#

UNC path is recognised as valid on an application deployed on most machines apart from two. They have read or read/write permissions. How can I fix this?

It is the Directory Exists in C#:

For example, using a hypothetical  UNC path  @"\test server\test first folder\second folder\third folder\Final destination";

then with all but two users this code works:
bool  exists;

```
        if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            exists = false;
        }
        else
        {

            Directory.GetAccessControl(textBox1.Text);
            exists = Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox1.Text));
           // MessageBox.Show(exists.ToString(),"Directory", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        //
        // The user selected a folder and pressed the OK button.
        // A message pops up and identifies the number of files found within that folder.
        //
        //textBox1.Text = f.FileName; //OpenFile dialog f FileName
        if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty )
        {

                    MessageBox.Show("No directory selected","Directory",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
        else if (exists == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Directory does not exist", "Directory", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);



        }
```

it finds the path (it is valid). But with the two users they get a "Path does not exist. Verify that the path is correct"  error.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In your real example, do you have two leading slashes, not the one you show in your question?

Comment: Unclear to me what you are asking, but how about using the debugger and inspecting the values of your variables?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.
If you say it is working on most machines, most likely, the issue is not with your code but rather with your underlying network setup or the string you are entering in the textbox (keep in mind that a UNC path should always start with 2 backslashes).

As a suggestion you might try to access the UNC path trough explorer (assuming you're talking about Windows machines) on the two machines where your code is not working. If you can't access it this way, you're code won't be able to either.